# Issue with FullCalendar 6 eventClick popover positioning

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, popover, fullcalendar-6

I'm currently working on implementing a FullCalendar 6 with eventClick functionality that opens a popover with additional details about the clicked event. However, I'm facing an issue with the popover positioning. I want the popover to appear next to the clicked event, but it's not working as expected.

```
eventClick: function(info) {
    var html = `<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <span class="d-none" id="publicId"> ${info.event.publicId } </span>
        </div>
    </div>`;     
    html += `<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">Start</div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">: ${ luxon.DateTime.fromISO(info.event.start).toFormat('LLLL d, yyyy') } </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-5">Duration</div>
       <div class="col-sm-7">: ${ info.extended.duration } </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-5">End</div>
       <div class="col-sm-7">: ${ luxon.DateTime.fromISO(info.event.end).toFormat('LLLL d, yyyy') } </div>
    </div>`;
    html += `<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <button id="btnEdit" class="btn btn xs btn-primary">Edit</button>
            <button id="btnDelete" class="btn btn xs btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>`;
    $(".popover").remove();
    $(info.el).popover({
        html:true,
        title: event.title + '<button type="button" class="close btn-close"></button>',
        content: html,
        placement:'auto',
        container: 'body',
        sanitize: false
    }).popover('show');
}
```

I've noticed that the popover is not positioning correctly next to the event when clicked. How can I ensure that the popover appears next to the clicked event? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with PHP, please remove tag. Also place your code in SO Snippet so that we can actually see what's wrong. Maybe you have some padding on element and that creates gap?